# how to access json key and value in the given json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a gigantic json object, and I need to find and access the key from the json in node.js.

json:

```
{ validationCode: 0,
  transactionEnvelope:
   { signature: <Buffer 30 45 02 21 00 94 15 9e e9 13 30 2a 2c 57 0f 8e fc d5 91 31 5b 7a df a1 ec f2 f2 a5 71 19 59 b8 7f 0e ff 33 f5 02 20 1d 20 b5 93 89 cf 9f f0 d4 97 35 ... >,
     payload:
      { header:
         { channel_header:
            { type: 'ENDORSER_TRANSACTION',
              version: 3,
              timestamp: 'Wed Jan 10 2018 21:25:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
              channel_id: 'mychannel',
              tx_id: '827f8c7bce4b1f64e7380767be9400e367d5d192ae6713a7ca07c56ecfb6dff0',
              epoch: 0,
              extension: <Buffer 12 06 12 04 74 72 61 69> },
           signature_header:
            { creator:
               { Mspid: 'Org1MSP',
                 IdBytes: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\no2HkWiuxLsibGxtE\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' },
              nonce: <Buffer f9 21 fe ac 10 59 93 78 76 65 15 f8 d2 cb 9a c9 cd 57 0b b9 78 da 2a b5> } },
        data:
         { actions:
            [ { header:
                 { creator:
                    { Mspid: 'Org1MSP',
                      IdBytes: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\no2HkWiuxLsibGxtE\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' },
                   nonce: <Buffer f9 21 fe ac 10 59 93 78 76 65 15 f8 d2 cb 9a c9 cd 57 0b b9 78 da 2a b5> },
                payload:
                 { chaincode_proposal_payload: { input: <Buffer 0a 9e 01 08 01 12 06 12 04 74 72 61 69 1a 91 01 0a 16 50 72 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 52 65 67 69 73 74 72 61 74 69 6f 6e 0a 77 7b 22 4d 6f 62 69 6c 65 ... > },
                   action:
                    { proposal_response_payload:
                       { proposal_hash: 'b0240ba97f5a8d26f61c38cd8d5b27cb8b53ed0049bd61ba9b286392328f8b44',
                         extension:
                          { results:
                             { data_model: 0,
                               ns_rwset:
                                [ { namespace: 'lscc',
                                    rwset:
                                     { reads:
                                        [ { key: 'abc001',
                                            version:
                                             { block_num: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: true },
                                               tx_num: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: true } } } ],
                                       range_queries_info: [],
                                       writes: [] } },
                                  { namespace: 'abc001',
                                    rwset:
                                     { reads:
                                        [ { key: '1234',
                                            version:
                                             { block_num: Long { low: 7, high: 0, unsigned: true },
                                               tx_num: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: true } } } ],
                                       range_queries_info: [],
                                       writes:
                                        [ { key: '1234',
                                            is_delete: false,
                                            value: '{"Codeno":"12345"}' } ] } } ] },
                            events:
                             { chaincode_id: '',
                               tx_id: '',
                               event_name: '',
                               payload: <Buffer > },
                            response: { status: 200, message: '', payload: '' } } },
                      endorsements:
                       [ { endorser:
                            { Mspid: 'Org1MSP',
                              IdBytes: '-----BEGIN -----\nMIICGjCCAcCgAwIBAgIRAPlwF/rUZUP9mqN4wSml4iswCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwczEL\nMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\ncmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMTE2Nh\nLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTcwODMxMDkxNDMyWhcNMjcwODI5MDkxNDMy\nWjBbMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMN\nU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEfMB0GA1UEAxMWcGVlcjAub3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTBZ\nMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABHihxW6ks3B2+5XdbAVq3CBgxRRRZ22x\nzzpqnD86nKkz7fBElBuhlXl2K6rTxyY2OBOB0ts8keqZ93xueRGymrajTTBLMA4G\nA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMCsGA1UdIwQkMCKAIEI5qg3Ndtru\nuLoM2nAYUdFFBNMarRst3dusalc2Xkl8MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIQD4j0Rn\ne1rrd0FSCzsR6u+IuuPK5dI/kR/bh7+VLf0TNgIgCfUtkJvfvzVEwZLFoFyjoHtr\ntvwzNUS1U0hEqIaDeo4=\n-----END -----\n' },
                           signature: <Buffer 30 44 02 20 1c 00 1f c6 3a 50 55 56 7e 8e d9 e9 27 5b 6b be b2 6f d1 ce 0f 6d a0 10 0a 91 dc 7d eb 17 ca 3a 02 20 1c 48 29 2c b8 54 76 47 43 2b a1 7b ... > } ] } } } ] } } } }
```

How do I access block_num low value : 7 under namespace: `abc001`?

I have other fields also, I tried and got:

```
var txnid = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.header.channel_header.tx_id;
var version = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.header.channel_header.version;
var timestamp = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.header.channel_header.timestamp;
var type  = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.header.channel_header.type;
```

When I use the same methodology its not working for blocknum. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hmm, what exact code are you using to try and access blocknum?

Comment: In the future, to avoid downvotes, you should have posted the methodology you used that was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some complex json. My recommendation for finding elements, is to keep trying one level at a time. This is usually how my thought process goes:

```
query_responses.transactionEnvelope;
// Good got object
query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload
// Another object, still good
query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data
// Wait, this is an array? How do I get the payload
query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data.actions.payload
// Nope, payload doesn't work on actions, as it's not an object
query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data.actions[0]
// Awesome, have an object again now, let's access payload:
query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data.actions[0].payload
```

block_num should be located at:

```
var blockNumber = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data.actions[0].payload.action.proposal_response_payload.extension.results.ns_rwset[1].rwset.reads[0].version.block_num;
```

If you're looking to filter by name for `ns_rwset`, you can use this:

```
var abcRwset = query_responses.transactionEnvelope.payload.data.actions[0].payload.action.proposal_response_payload.extension.results.ns_rwset
    .find(rwset => rwset.namespace === 'abc001');

var blockNumber = abcRwset.rwset.reads[0].version.block_num;
```